# curl PATCH - JSON is sent as Line-based text data

Tags: json, curl, swagger, patch

Using curl to send a PATCH to my web service and got error:

```
Bad Request, The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
```

while sending GET and POST using curl have no issue.
Using Swagger sending the same PATCH has no issue. So using WireShark to compare the Swagger (good) case and curl (bad) case.

Swagger (good) case:
[image: Swagger (good) case]

curl (bad) case:
[image: curl (bad) case]

In the good case, a 0xA is inserted after "{" and ",". curl doesn't do this and double quotes are missing.

Here is the Swagger UI:
[image: Swagger UI (good)]

and this is my curl command running on Windows Command Prompt
[image: curl command (bad)]

Chrome app ARC also gets OK response:
[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was fixed by following curl:

```
curl --request PATCH "http://......................" ^
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
    --header "Accept: application/json" ^
    --header "Authorization: ..............." ^
    --data "{\"op\":\"add\",\"path\":\"/user\",\"value\":\"%~1\"}"
```

Because it runs on Windows.